# System is not defined error in systejs.config.js

Tags: angular, typescript, model-view-controller

Hi I have created MVC application that uses angular 2 component.
I have app folder that contains component,module and main.ts.
I have added `package.json`,`tsconfig` and `systemjs.config.js`.

If I run the application in one html page it is working but when I include the angular component in layout page its giving me

> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined.

I have included following lines in `systemjs.config.js`

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>   
<script src="node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>

<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

Systemjs.config.js contains following code

```
System.config({

transpiler: 'typescript', 
paths: {
      'npm:': '../node_modules/'
},
    map: {

  app: 'app',


  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',


  'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
},

packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.ts',
    defaultExtension: 'ts'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us what's in your `systemjs.config.js`.

Comment: Are you also pointing to the right `system.src.js`? Try deleting the `node_modules`, then reinstalling.

Comment: (function (global) {
  System.config({
 //use typescript for compilation
 transpiler: 'typescript', 
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '../node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: '../app',
 '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
     
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.ts',
        defaultExtension: 'ts'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);

Comment: Can you place it in your question instead?

Comment: i have deleted node_modules files then reinstalled but not working

Comment: Can you try importing `system.js` instead of `system.src.js`?

Comment: Please let me know anyone has solution